# sprintf function takes hex values and create a string with all the ACII values

Tags: c

I'm using a sprintf function in C.
I created a first working program in this way:

```
sprintf((char*)(command),"\"\x1F\"\r");
```

This is working properly because it prints the corresponding ASCII caracters for this particular hex values that is 0x1F.

Next point is that I want to to the same things but with a variable:

```
sprintf((char*)(command),"\"\\x%x\"\r",var);
```

I tried in differents ways but is not working.

Expected output is something like this "�u}��"
That correpond to the hex values after conversion in ASCII"
If I'm using a variable I get only the 1F print.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly .. you want to print the ASCII character for a specific hex value which is stored inside a variable?

Comment: `sprintf(command, "\"%c\"\r", (char) var)` (Cast needed if `var` is not a `char` variable)

Comment: Define "is not working".  What output did you expect, and what output did you get?

Comment: By the way, why do you have that explicit conversion (cast) for `command`? That's highly suspicous.

Comment: Please post all of the code.   We need to be able to see how ```command``` is declared, and more...

Comment: @DanielJour yes It's working if I directly write the hexadecimal value inside the sprintf.
sprintf((char*)(command),"\"\x1F\"\r"); <-- Working

Comment: Rather than `%x` maybe use `%02X`

Comment: What is type of `var`?  `%x` expects int-size variable---if it's not an `int` or `unsigned int`, you'll need to cast it to one, or use a length modifier in the format string, like `%lx`.  (Also, more details of the actual wrong behavior would be helpful.)

Comment: `"\x1F"` is converted at the time the compiler parses the string. But `"%x"` isn't parsed until runtime. So you can't make up the first value by using `"\x%x"`.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks for the comments yes I read about this things in other questions do you have any workaround to solve the problem?

Comment: Lets say you have `int var = 48;` (and assuming ASCII) would you expect to print the digit character `'0'`? You do that by printing the value as a *character*, not as an integer. For example, `printf("\\x%x", 48)` will print the string `\x30` (that literal string will be printed), but `printf("%c", 48)` will print the string `0`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "(Cast needed if var is not a char variable)" is not supported by `printf("%c", 48)` will print the string `0`.  The cast needed if `var` is a not a  `char, signed char, unsigned char, short, unsigned short, int` (and perhaps `unsigned)`.  `"%c"` expects an `int` argument (after the usual promotions).  "If no l length modifier is present, the int argument is converted to an unsigned char, and the resulting character is written."

Comment: @nicola ferrante, after forming `command`, how is it used?  How was `command` defined?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly you have an "ASCII value" (for example 0x1F) which you get from some source of input (say the user), and want to display this value (or rather, the corresponding ASCII character.

```c
char const ascii_value = 0x1F;
printf("\"%c\"\r", ascii_value);
```

The conversion format specifier `%c` expects a parameter of type `char` and will display just that character (so not "1F" but the rather unprintable "unit separator").

Of course, for `char` values you don't really need this .. as a `char var = 0x1F` *is* already the "ASCII character" you want. To illustrate this a bit further:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char manually[20] = {0};
    manually[0] = '"';
    manually[1] = 0x1F; // Direct assignment of value 0x1F to char
    manually[2] = '"';
    manually[3] = '\r';
    char buffer[20] = {0};
    snprintf(buffer, 20, "\"\x1F\"\r");
    if (memcmp(manually, buffer, 20) == 0)
    {
        puts("Same");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("Different");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This will output "Same". (https://ideone.com/3pr51b)

Answer (score 0):

Processing the escape sequence `\x` is not done by `sprintf()`, it's done by the compiler when converting the string literal to data. So when you write `"\"\x1F\""`, the string literal actually contains a byte with code `0x1f`

So formatting a string with literal `\x` produced by `\\x` will not cause it to be treated as an escape sequence.

If you want to put the byte value in the result, use `%c`

```
sprintf(command, "\"%c\"", var);
```